# Struct. pack error in python 3 - struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct.pack

I know this question has been asked before, and some of the suggestions seem to be about needing a b to make the string a byte literal. However, im passing hex code to the function as 0x414243 to save it as ABC.

```
def _pack(_data, size):
    numofbytes = size/8
    print("Chars Expected: " + str(numofbytes))
    formatString = "{}s".format(int(numofbytes))
    print("Formatted String:" + formatString)
    struct.pack(formatString,_data)

_pack(0x414243,24)
```

I'm not sure what to change here,  im wondering if its a problem with how im using formatstring variable. I want the function to be able to work out how many chars are in the passed data from the size and in this case 24 bits = 3 bytes so it formats 3s  and passes 0x414243 to convert to ABC.

Can anyone advise how to get past the error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `struct.pack()` wants a group of bytes and you're giving it an integer.

If you want to be able to pass the data in as an integer, convert it to bytes before packing it:

```
_data = _data.to_bytes(numofbytes, "big")   # or "little", depending on endianness
```

Or just pass the data in as bytes when you call it:

```
_pack(b"0x410x420x43", 24)
```

If you have a string containing hexadecimal, such as `"0x414243"`, you can convert it to an integer, then on to bytes:

```
_data = int(_data, 16).to_bytes(numofbytes, "big")
```

You might use `isinstance()` to allow your function to accept any of these formats:

```
if isinstance(_data, str):
    _data = int(_data, 16)
if isinstance(_data, int):
    _data = _data.to_bytes(numofbytes, "big")
```

By the way, your calculation of the number of bytes will produce a floating-point answer if `size` is not a multiple of 8. A fractional number of bytes is an error. To address this:

```
numofbytes = size // 8 + bool(size % 8)
```

The `+ bool(size % 8)` bit adds one to the result of the integer division if there are any bits left over.

Comment: nevermind i just re read you post.  however when i pass it big i get output CBA when i pass it small i get \x00\x00\x00  how do i get the output ABC

Comment: The `b` tells Python how to parse a string literal; you can't "add it" programmatically. By the time you've written `"0x414243"` the data's already a string, not bytes. But you could parse it to an integer using `int(data, 16)` and then proceed as above to convert that integer to bytes. I'll add that.

Comment: Also if i make this changers and add abother char to the imput i.e  0x41424341 and pass 32 i get a memory error.